# Wordpress: Print all (entire) pages on page.php instead of loading them individually

Tags: jquery, wordpress, vertical-scrolling, jquery-scrollable

I’m creating a site in wordpress which are using the jQuery scrolling function for the page layout. It have to scroll vertical. But for doing this I need all the pages to be displayed on the page.php site instead of loading each page separately.

Is it possible to do some kind of foreach loop and print out all the pages in wordpress?

I hope you understand otherwise please let me know and I’ll elaborate.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page'
  );
query_posts($args);
?>
```